# Maximum length of column comments in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the maximum length of a comment for a column in snowflake?

Documentation site:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/comment.html

Syntax:
COMMENT [IF EXISTS] ON <object_type> <object_name> IS '<string_literal>';

COMMENT [IF EXISTS] ON COLUMN <table_name>.<column_name> IS '<string_literal>';

Thank you.

Comment: do you have a need that you can share "we need to put 1024 bytes in each comment" that can be tested, or are you trying to find the upper limit, so you can work within it?

Comment: `"SNOWFLAKE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS"` system view contains `COMMENT VARCHAR(16777216)` - that's the metadata theoretical limit. Is there anything besides that? I'd be curious too.

Comment: We are planning to add field definitions in the table field comments and want to know the what the character limit is.  It sounds like all of our definitions should fit.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical limit is 16777216.
`"SNOWFLAKE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS"` view contains `COMMENT VARCHAR(16777216)`.

The longest comment I can see in all the system tables is 327.

```
select comment, length(comment) from "SNOWFLAKE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" 
where COMMENT is not null
order by length(comment) desc;
```